# How to remove a file stuck in unstated files?

Tags: git, repository

I`ve been working on a project in git. It`s an mobile app and I need to store in git some images.
My problem is that for some reason one of these image got stuck as a changed file forever. I want to discard those changes.

What I tried:
 - git rm --cached 
 - git update-index --assume-unchanged 
 - git checkout -- .
 - delete the entire repo and checkout it again
 - stash the changes
 - discard the changes via Source Tree

Nothing worked!
My guess is that there are two images under git and git is getting confusing by some other version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git for some reason got two versions of the same file!

This is how I solved this issue:

- Renamed the unstated file
- Committ changes
- The problematic file appeared in my folder
- Committ changes to the file

The solution is simple but it took me a while to discover that I was dealing with two versions of the same file.